# What is the best way to check whether a signal is a valid one in SystemC?

Tags: c++, systemc

I am having a little problem in a SystemC simulation because in one component I did forget to check for signals integrity and my simulation breaks because of this. Basically I do not handle situations when my signals are like `"XXXXX..."` or `"ZZZZ..."`!

How to check that a signal is a valid one? Meaning not `"ZZZZ..."`, not `"XXXX..."` but a valid one like `"000110..."`?
Thankyou

### A little detail

Someone pointed out that maybe here I am asking about checking whether a signal is a number or not. Ok, let's say that if the signal is valid it is a number of course. But I experienced in some debugging sessions that `"XXX..."` signals are sometimes treated like -1 or negative numbers in general... So that is why I did not ask about how to check whether a signal is a number or not...

Comment: Hard to understand what is asked here. If you want numbers then check if what you got are numbers.

Comment: Well, basically if it is a valid signal it is a number so the question might turn like: "how to check if the signal is a number", but I do not know whether systemc treats X and Z like -1 or similar... This is my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sc_logic.is_01()?

```
bool is_01() const;
```

from 7.9.2.2  at page 259 of the [IEEE Std 1666-2011](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1666/download/1666-2011.pdf).

Comment: Oh... Well quite simple answer!!! it is strange, I searched in the library, I missed it probably, thanks a lot... gonna try this!

Comment: A similar method for array of sc_logic?

Comment: I thought it was the same.  The class 'sc_bv_base' has the same method .

Comment: Sorry for asking, I checked the doc a moment ago and, yes, it is exactly like you said! Thanks a lot.